# What happens if Fortitude sinks to 0?

Tags: dnd-4e

I'm currently DMing a campaign (a ready adventure), where a monster can drain Fortitude inposing -2 penalty to it (save ends). The power description says that it's cumulative.

The question is: what should happen when Fortitude drops to 0 after multiple attacks?

Comment: what monster is this?

Comment: Fortitude. And it is 4e. Gray Ooze from Slaying Stone adventure

Comment: In Pathfinder, a 0 stat kills you. That's what you might have been thinking of.

Comment: @waxeagle Or Gray Ooze from Monster Manual 2

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Attacks vs Fortitude almost automatically hit.

Fortitude is a defense, it is nothing more than that. If your fortitude is 0, then attacks against your fortitude will hit (unless they are in turn an automiss (a 1 on the die roll)).

There are no game consequences to this beyond the fact that you become ridiculously easy to hit.

More importantly, this is almost entirely unlikely to happen. Even in the worst case, a PC's fortitude may be 8, and then it'd take 4 hits without a save before the PC was reduced to 0. This *might* happen but it would be incredibly rare.

Ultimately though, a defense reduced to 0 has no effect other than that the defense is 0. It could even be negative.